# How to just read the current ringer volume of device in an ios app programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I just want to know how to read the current ringer volume set by user in applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions: method.

I search on net but came up with many confusing answers. Tried a few but did not work. Most are just to read the media volume.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying things out, you can use [MPMusicPlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html). It has a property called `volume` which will give you the current volume level.

If you plain submitting to the App Store, i suggest you use this. [MPVolumeView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The volume property of MPMusicPlayerController is deprecated. The view will get you the same thing, but I didn't find a volume property.

Here's something that I've used before. Hopefully it helps.

```
    MPVolumeView *volume = [[[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18.0, 340.0, 284.0, 23.0)] autorelease];
  [[self view] addSubview:volume];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(volumeChanged:) 
                                        name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification" 
                                        object:nil];    
  for (UIView *view in [volume subviews]){
    if ([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"MPVolumeSlider"]) {
      volumeViewSlider = view;  //volumeViewSlider is a UIView * object
    }
  }
  [volumeViewSlider _updateVolumeFromAVSystemController];

-(IBAction)volumeChanged:(id)sender{
  [volumeViewSlider _updateVolumeFromAVSystemController];
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but MPVolumeView shows interface to user for interaction, but I just needed some way to do it programmatically. Also tried checking the volume property for MPVolumeView, but its just not there.

Comment: In that case, you use the notification center to check if its changed at any point. AVFoundation will have a setter for the volume.